# Can anyone recommend a simple screenshot tool that can be installed as a portable app?

Tags: windows, screenshot, community-faq-proposed, portable-apps

The printscreen button doesn't work on our university computers, so I'm looking for a simple free screenshot tool that can be installed on a USB drive.

this question is similar:
https://superuser.com/questions/254/screenshot-utilities-for-windows
though I'm looking for something specifically portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[FastStone Capture](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=775) fits the bill quite well.

Comment: Ideal. simple UI with window capture or user specified area (as well as others). opens the screenshot straight away. number of saveas options. Unzip to USB drive

Comment: It costs money apparently. Only **30** days trial

Comment: @vsync incorrect; quote from the website: Note: FastStone Capture went payware starting from v5.4 so I have made the last freeware version available (v5.3) for direct download as the license agreement does not prohibit redistribution.

Answer (score 2):

[Lightscreen Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/lightscreen_portable) is another alternative.

Comment: Unfortuately wouldn't install on my USB because of 'restrictions' in place on the University computers (possibly blocking installers?). May well suit others needs.

Answer (score 1):

One more to the list which I have used extensively is [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/) which uses <kbd>Print screen</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print screen</kbd> as shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to this part but many consider [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/) the best screen captured program and it comes in a portable version too