# Portable Screen Capture App

Tags: display, portable, focus, capture, contrast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recommend a simple screenshot tool that can be installed as a portable app?](https://superuser.com/questions/195509/can-anyone-recommend-a-simple-screenshot-tool-that-can-be-installed-as-a-portable)

... that quickly facilitates the de-focusing of inverted selections (I.e., Capture screen, select portion of screen capture : press hot-key / click button : and (hopefully, although a default with a hot-key would be good) have options to choose from, to de-focus inverted selection - like reduced contrast, b&w conversion, etc.

Comment: @studiohack Which question is this an exact duplicate of, I only have 1 question submitted under my account (this one)?

Comment: @studiohack Have read through the above possible duplicate post, and the link to the other post in it, and cannot see anyone who tells me of a program that easily facilitates the difference in contrast between what I want to be focused on, and what is just for setting, like in this pic http://img841.imageshack.us/i/delk.png