# Portable Screen Capture App

Tags: focus, contrast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can anyone recommend a simple screenshot tool that can be installed as a portable app?](https://superuser.com/questions/195509/can-anyone-recommend-a-simple-screenshot-tool-that-can-be-installed-as-a-portable)

... that quickly facilitates the de-focusing of inverted selections (I.e., Capture screen, select portion of screen capture : press hot-key / click button : and (hopefully, although a default with a hot-key would be good) have options to choose from, to de-focus inverted selection - like reduced contrast, b&w conversion, etc.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: @Dennis very true, it's amazing how posting a question shows related questions, is overlooked. In the future I'm just going to glance over the _Related_ list on unanswered questions before answering.

Comment: People - I am not asking for a stock standard screen capture utility(!) - All "duplicates" are asking for JUST a portable screen capture utility, which them Google'ng for would have been much faster than posting a question here. I am asking for a screen capture tool that does something very SPECIFIC... STOP CLOSING MY QUESTIONS... Wesley has the answer exactly right, just a disappointment there is not a free alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update**: [Snagit is a commercial application](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit/features/win/) that does what you want:

> **Spotlight and magnify**
>
> Draw attention to a specific part of
>   your image. Just select the portion
>   you want and Snagit will blur and
>   darken everything else.

---

[Irfanview portable.](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=49) Press C to access the screen capture mode, timed or hotkey activated. It's a viewer that has many image manipulation functions as well.

[image]

Comment: I know of quite a few screen capture tools that allow what I want, but all of them take a dozen or more clicks to simply invert select and dim the rest of the screen (or other action to de-focus information you don't want people to pay too much attention to - Like this ... http://img841.imageshack.us/i/delk.png. Do you know if infanview does this?

Comment: With a click of a button? No. There are commercial ones that do, though. See the answer update. Aprt from paying, you can just do some image editing to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use PicPick. It's portable and has small editor

Comment: Thanks, but already looked at that, are required more clicks than wanted to perform this operation.